# How to write `has_many: through` with scope that references a through table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

How can I write a `:has_many` association with a where clause that references another table that I can also use with `:includes`?

Roughly, the code I would like is below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :as, -> {
    where('as.x >= bs.date_start and as.x <= bs.date_end')
  }, through: :bs
end
```

This works when I instantiate a particular model. For example

```
> u = User.find(1)
> u.as.to_a
[...] # I get results I want
```

However, I cannot use `:includes` on this association:

```
> User.includes(:as).where(id: [1])
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'as.x' in 'where clause': SELECT `bs`.* FROM `bs` WHERE (as.x >= bs.date_start and as.x < bs.date_end) AND `bs`.`id` IN (1)
```

How can I rewrite my code so that I can use `:includes` on my association?

---

EDIT: I tried rewriting the association like this, but it didn't work:

```
has_many, :as, -> (b) {
  where('as.x >= ? and as.x <= ?', b.date_start, bs.date_end)
}, through: bs

> u = User.find(1)
> u.as
NoMethodError: undefined method 'date_start' for #<User:...>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `.references(:as)` if you need it on your query. `User.includes(:as).references(:as).where(id: [1])`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references

Comment: This does work, but it seems less than ideal because callers must remember to chain the `:references` or they will get an error. Includes the `references` in that scope doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You could have a class method / named scope that returns `self.includes(:as).references(:as)` if you want to alias that.